# Trouble connecting Colab Local Runtime to Google Cloud TPU VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, tpu

I'm trying to run a Google Colab notebook on a TPU VM that I created on Google Cloud, following the instructions here (https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/run-calculation-jax#install_the_google_cloud_sdk and https://github.com/google-research/t5x/blob/main/t5x/notebooks/README.md). I'm able to instantiate the VM just fine, and everything seems to work until the last step, where I need to port-forward to the running Jupyter notebook session in my local runtime on Colab.
Following the answers here and elsewhere I tried the following:

1. https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html says to run this command:

`gcloud compute ssh --zone YOUR_ZONE YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8888:localhost:8888`
When I do this on my local M1 terminal, it says
`ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource: projects/<PROJNAME>/zones/europe-west4-a/instances/<YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME>`
was not found. This is even as `gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm describe <YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME> --zone=europe-west4-a` shows me the running session.

2. I also ran the following in the Colab notebook to make sure the notebook is running under the same project:
   `!gcloud config set project <PROJNAME>`
3. I checked that the Jupyter notebook session is indeed created with `--NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'`

I also swapped `gcloud compute` with `gcloud alpha compute` but none of these seems to have addressed the problem. I'd be grateful if you have any suggestions or notice any obvious mistakes I'm making.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might have had something to do with the fact that I followed the first few steps on the Cloud Shell terminal in the browser, instead of on my local terminal. I did the following the next day, all on my laptop terminal and it connected super smoothly:

```
gcloud init 
gcloud config set project <PROJNAME>
gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm ssh <YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME> --zone=europe-west4-a -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
```

Connected via Colab using the Connect to Local Runtime option. I did get a TimeOut error the first 2 tries but then it worked.